# SQL Server Dynamic Search Based on Stored Search Parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have to create a dynamic search. The search criteria is stored in tables and there is a main table for the stored records. Here is the structure:

```
--Main Table. This table stores records of a user. Basically we store files in this table. Each file is associated with a single city.
DECLARE @Records TABLE(
[RecordId] INT IDENTITY(1,1),
[FileName] VARCHAR(100),
[OwnerId] INT,
[CityId] INT
)
INSERT INTO @Records
SELECT 'A', 100, 101 UNION
SELECT 'B', 100, 102 UNION
SELECT 'C', 100, 103 UNION
SELECT 'D', 100, 104

--The next table is used to associate a file with multiple friends.
DECLARE @FriendRecords TABLE
(
[Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1),
[RecordId] INT,
[FriendId] INT
)
INSERT INTO @FriendRecords
SELECT 1, 201 UNION --File '1' is associated with 'FriendId' 201
SELECT 1, 202 UNION --File '1' is associated with 'FriendId' 202
SELECT 2, 201 UNION --File '2' is associated with 'FriendId' 201
SELECT 3, 202       --File '3' is associated with 'FriendId' 202

--The following table is used to create a criteria for user.
DECLARE @Criteria TABLE
(
[CriteriaId] INT IDENTITY(1,1),
[CriteriaName] VARCHAR(50),
[OwnerId] INT
)
INSERT INTO @Criteria
SELECT 'SampleCriteria', 100 --Criteria created by user 100

--The following table is used to store cities that needs to be searched in 'Records' table for owner of criteriaId '1'.
DECLARE @CriteriaCities TABLE(
[CriteriaCityId] INT IDENTITY(1,1),
[CriteriaId] INT, 
[CityId] INT
)
INSERT INTO @CriteriaCities
SELECT 1, 101 UNION
SELECT 1, 102 UNION
SELECT 1, 103 

--The following table is used to store friend that needs to be searched in 'FriendsRecords' table for owner of criteriaId '1'.
DECLARE @CriteriaFriend TABLE(
[CriteriaCityId] INT IDENTITY(1,1),
[CriteriaId] INT, 
[FriendId] INT
)
INSERT INTO @CriteriaFriend
SELECT 1, 202;
```

Basically, the user can create a criteria(@Criteria table) and store the search parameters(@CriteriaCities and @CriteriaFriend tables.) The requirement is to get the files according to the stored criteria. The query I am looking for should return records from @Records table that has cityIds 101, 102&103 **AND** FriendId '201'. The result is only 'C' from @Records table. If I create a left join on all the tables, I get the other records for ownerId '100' as well. If I include an inner join within tables I get no records if there is no entry for criteria in @CriteriaCities or @CriteriaFriend table. What should be the query that searches for records in the main table based on record that exist in the link tables(@CriteriaCities, @CriteriaFriend)? If the search parameter is not stored in these table the join should not be created between these tables.

Comment: Why is this such a complicated process?  What is the reason for this design?  Also, in your example, if you are searching for `CityID` of `101`,`102` or `103` and a `FriendID` of `201`, doesn't that match File `A` and `B` instead of `C`?  Even if you use `FriendID` of `202` as per your script. you would match with `A` and `C`.  How are you just getting File `C` as your output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you have your logic fully understood as your question doesn't quite make sense per my comment, but if I follow what you have stated as your rules you can use the following `select` statement to get your data.  I am not sure how you would pass in which criteria you are searching for yet though, as you have not explained how this part of your process works:

```
-- Count the records in each criteria table.
declare @CriteriaCitiesCount int = (select count(1) from @CriteriaCities);
declare @CriteriaFriendCount int = (select count(1) from @CriteriaFriend);


select *
from @Records r
    left join @CriteriaCities cc
        on(r.CityId = cc.CityId)
    left join @FriendRecords f
        on(r.RecordId = f.RecordId)
    left join @CriteriaFriend cf
        on(f.FriendId = cf.FriendId)
where (@CriteriaCitiesCount = 0        -- Only return records where we aren't filtering,
        or cc.CityId is not null       -- Or we are filtering and we get a match.
        )
    and (@CriteriaFriendCount = 0
        or cf.FriendId is not null
        );
```

Comment: Yes. You are correct. FriendId "202" will give A and C. My mistake. I just created temporary tables and mingled the actual values. Anyways, as per your answer, if there is no record in "@CriteriaFriend" table for [OwnerId] 100 the results will be blank. Whereas my requirement is "if there is no record in the "@CriteriaFriend" table don't create a join. Same goes with "@CriteriaCities" table.

Comment: That worked, though I had to make some tweaks. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,i am not able to understand your output.
Why you should get only FileName C ?

Try something like,

```
;With CTE as
(
select cc.CityId,cf.FriendId    
from @Criteria C
inner join @CriteriaCities CC
on c.CriteriaId=cc.CriteriaId
inner join @CriteriaFriend CF  
on c.CriteriaId=cf.CriteriaId
where c.OwnerId=@ownerid
)

select *
from @Records R
inner join @FriendRecords FR
on r.RecordId=fr.RecordId
where EXISTS(
select cityid from cte c where r.CityId=c.cityid and c.FriendId=fr.FriendId
)
```